# Race condition when cancelling tasks during app deactivation

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8, async-await, lifetime

I'm trying to use Task-based asynchronous pattern in my Windows Phone 8 app. Idea is that all long-running operations have reference to a cancellation token, and there's one place in app where all those tokens are stored. When app receives `Deactivated` event, it iterates through all the tokens and cancels them.

The problem is that the thread with long-running operation is not scheduled to run when app deactivates, and this means if I'm trying to use `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` in that thread, it's only called when app resumes, not when app deactivates. And of course this is not what I want. If I'm doing a simple trick like `token.Register(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));`, i.e. pausing thread which calls to cancellation for a moment, then second thread has a chance to run, and everything is cancelled like a charm. However, this is a dirty hack and I don't want to use it in my app.

The question is how to make sure app is not exiting while operation cancellation is finished? I assume that sign of cooperative cancellation is OperationCancelledException thrown, but how to wait for it, especially if I only have a reference to CancellationTokenSource, but not to the Task object? Is there some other way to know about that?

Much thanks in advance!

P.S. If you need more code to help me, just ask.

Comment: Why is that not what you want? Why does it matter than the operation is actually canceled only after the application resumes?

Comment: My worker thread does not receive notification about cancellation, that's the problem. It's supposed to stop writing to a file and close it properly on cancellation request, then throw OperationCancelledException as a confirmation of successful cancellation. If it will not happen before app deactivation, file could be left in some unexpected state, since app could be killed after deactivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think storing all the `CancellationToken`s in not enough in your case, you also need to store the corresponding `Task`s. In your `Deactivated` handler, you would then cancel all the tokens and then `await` all the stored `Task`s (catching the `OperationCancelledException`s). (I'm not sure how exactly does `Deactivated` work with `async`, you might need something to let the system know that you haven't actually finished deactivating yet.)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, and I think it should work. However, I have a problem with implementation. Do you think it make sense to add details to this question or to create a separate one?